# What is the best way to dereference values within chains of iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator

When I'm using iterators, I often find myself needing to explicitly dereference values. The following code finds the sum of all pairs of elements in a vector:

```rust
extern crate itertools;

use crate::itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let x: Vec<i32> = (1..4).collect();

    x.iter()
        .combinations(2)
        .map(|xi| xi.iter().map(|bar| **bar)
        .sum::<i32>())
        .for_each(|bar| println!("{:?}", bar));
}
```

Is there a better way of performing the dereferencing than using a `map`?

Even better would be a way of performing these types of operations without explicitly dereferencing at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `xi.iter()` means that you are explicitly asking for an iterator of *references* to the values within `xi`. Since you don't want references in this case and instead want the actual values, you'd want to use `xi.into_iter()` to get an iterator for the values.

So you can change

```
.map(|xi| xi.iter().map(|bar| **bar).sum::<i32>())
```

to

```
.map(|xi| xi.into_iter().sum::<i32>())
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63f1c4ad4505f5d97121decf7d274e04)

Comment: Are there any downsides to using into_iter()?

Comment: Nope, whether you use `iter`, `iter_mut` or `into_iter` just depends on what types you want output.

Comment: Thanks! I actually started out using into_iter(), but then I waylaid thinking about ownership.

Comment: The documentation lists two implementations of into_iter, one for the Iterator trait, and one for the IntoIterator trait, and the later says it is consuming. How do you know which is used, and thus whether it is safe to use x afterwords?